# How to scrape page element using xpath

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, html-parsing, scraper

I want to get email of element using xpath

```
<td>
<span id="A-1_id_1151_1997" class="">info@alexianer.com</span>
</td>
```

I have tried many codes and one of them is this

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.deutsches-krankenhaus-verzeichnis.de/suche/Krankenhaus/260530089-00-1.1/Alexianer-Aachen-GmbH.jsf');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( '//*[@id="accordion"]/table[4]/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]' );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
```

if i use id then email is displaying but with TD tag its not, as page is dynamic and id changes on every page. i think the problem is with nodeValue but couldn't figure out.

Please provide any solution.

Comment: Xpath is bad choice, use CSS selector to extract data form HTML. for e.g td > span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining http://www.deutsches-krankenhaus-verzeichnis.de/suche/Krankenhaus/260530089-00-1.1/Alexianer-Aachen-GmbH.jsf it seems to me you can grab the nodes you want from that with something like the following XPath expression:

```xpath
//table[*[@class="tablehead"]/td/*[text()="E-Mail"]]//tr[2]/td[7]
```

That is, translated in prose, ”Find any `table` that has a child with a `class` attribute whose value is `tablehead` and which in turn has a `td` child which in turn has any child whose text content is “`E-Mail`”—and if you find such a `table`, get the 7th `td` child of the 2nd `tr` descendant of it.”

If you want to get only any `td` that contains a specific e-mail address, you can just check that the text context of the entire node matches that particular e-mail address, and if you only want to get the first such matching node, use the `[1]` position predicate against the whole expression:

```
(//table[*[@class="tablehead"]/td/*[text()="E-Mail"]]//tr[2]/td[7][.="info@alexianer-aachen.de"])[1]
```

Comment: Your answer shows your Brilliancy. exact email is coming, Only the issue is that other emails are coming along.

Comment: Also wondering how it find "class=tablehead" as this class is already repeated before.

Comment: About “Only the issue is that other emails are coming along”, see my updated answer.

Comment: About “Also wondering how it find "class=tablehead" as this class is already repeated before“, it does it by using it in the context of a specific predicate.